# Voting in elections through Android App

Tags: feature-request, android-app, election

Why is it not possible to vote in elections through the Android app directly?

Instead there is a link to the page, which opens in the browser. While this is fine, it would always be better if everything can be done from within the app itself.

<sub>([similar request for iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280596/let-me-vote-on-moderator-elections-via-the-ios-app))</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How often are there elections? Once a year? What would make it some important to be able to do this from the app? Isn't it just useless to spend so much time for something you use once or twice a year?

I don't think it is particularly useful to have this in the app.